# Как получить значение присвоенное в функции

Tags: javascript, node.js

В случае обычных функций нужно использовать return, а как поступить например с таким:

```js
function getFolder(){
    fs.readdir(main_folder+folders[0], (err, songs) => {
            return songs;
    });
    return songs;
}
```

через console.log видно что работает, но как вытащить из fs.readdir значения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

[async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```js
function getFolder() {
  return new Promise((s, e) =>
    fs.readdir(main_folder + folders[0], (err, songs) => {
      err ? e(err) : s(songs)
    })
  )
}

async function gf(){
  let songs = await getFolder()
}
```