# Записать данные json из файла в переменную

Tags: javascript, json, async-await, асинхронность, promise

Имею код

```
let data;

function getFile (fileName) {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', fileName);
    request.onload =  function() {
           data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

    };

    request.send();
}

getFile('/task/data.json'); //путь к файлу

console.log(data);
```

Из-за асинхронщины вероятно, когда вывожу в конце data получаю undefined. Нужно записать данные в переменную, использую только нативный js, наколько я понимаю, нужен аналог из jQuery типа $.getJSON

Comment: Просто подружись с [Promise](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1072462/305162)

Comment: чет все равно не получается