# Записать данные json из файла в переменную 2

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

```
let data;

function getFile (fileName) {

    let  request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', fileName);

    request.onloadend = function() {

        data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

    };

    request.send();
}

Promise.all([
    getFile('task/data.json'),
    getFile('task/names.json')
]).then(results => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Не работает последний console.log(data); Хотя должен.
Повтор вопроса [Записать данные json из файла в переменную](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1082966/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-json-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e)

Comment: Что это, простите, за хрень? Что тут вообще делают промисы, когда у Вас функция не асинхронная? Естественно, у Вас работать это не будет, ибо функции завершатся раньше, чем data будет присвоено значение

Comment: `const getFile = fileName => new Promise(function (resolve) { ... resolve(JSON.parse(request.responseText));... });`

Comment: Сделайте человеческую асинхронную функцию и просто возвращайте результат, а не изгаляйтесь с богомерзкими глобальными переменными

Answer (score 0):

Чтоб не использовать Promise

```js
// Эмуляция JSON - на это не стоит обращать внимание
//   это фиктивный http://
const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(['{"any":132}'],{ type:'application/json' }))

async function getData() {
  let d = await fetch(url)
  // Типа мы получили JSON
  return await d.json()
}

void async function () {
  let data = await getData()
  console.log(data)
}()
```

Comment: Хотите сказать, у Вас здесь нет `Promise`? :) *P.S. - минус не мой*

Comment: @Kir_Antipov уверен, что все поняли, о каком Promise идет речь. Хотел сказать, чтоб не использовать лишнюю обертку с каллбэком.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFile (fileName, ) {

    let  request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', fileName, false);

    request.send(null);

    return  JSON.parse(request.responseText);
}
let data = getFile('task/data.json');
let names = getFile('task/names.json');


console.log(data);
console.log(names);
```

Comment: Параметр `async = false`, является устаревшим, да еще и вредным. Подобные функции следует оборачивать в Promise. А лучше сразу заменить `XMLHttpRequest` на [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) с использованием `async/await`